# Application gets logged out when we come out and clear it in multi tasking

Tags: android, authentication, logout, onresume

I'm trying to create an Android Application with user Log-in and Log-out options. I've written a code where the user get logged-in successfully. But when I come out of the applicationa and clears it in multitasking the user details in the application gets logged out. Here's my code:

```
Login() {
    ConstantVariables.bVibes_userID = userId;
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(userId_sp, userId);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.i("userId_sp", "userId_sp" + userId_sp);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(userId_sp)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Dashboard_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Can anybody help me solving the issue. For me the user should not be logged out unless otherwise the user himself selects to or only when the application is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local file, where you would store the last log in data. If the file exists and contains username and password, then you should call the log in. If the login is unsuccessful or the login data is inexistent, then a logged out state is just fine.

Comment: @shkschneider, that's right, the file can be encoded or binary. The point is to have the password locally somewhere.